# accessing route params an return as string

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm looking to get route params from URL

```
created() {
        this.token = this.getTokenParam();

        console.log("Token " + this.token);
    }

    getTokenParam() : string {
        const t = this.$route.params.token
        console.log("Token " + this.$route.query.token);
        if(t === null) return ''
        else
        return t;
    }
```

Token

> CfDJ8JrtUPxIgVlCopul3de0MqTwaW1Hukhm9RMfMIsi7kWP/6u89xVvJ4iAbcWTCTgrYvE9tcqZjYb3QvXrdhNEM2xLT0Ut8jdDDnfa0sKJFdXE8wYNZDwegDgEOkCBrPC6IZ
>   h5qcDTSb OaohaeEpk8RJXtp
>   sDD3sDTs/gY2xdB3oxQIfnqaTtBoEI/6C/QtyOGqPW7pWaikG1pRe4uM9j/KDo
>   OWMDwUoI tll4CeyM

`Token undefined` (why undefined??)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you reading it from query params?

```
const t = this.$route.query.token
console.log("Token " + this.$route.query.token);
```

Comment: Initial on the first print. I'm reading it directly from this.$route.query.token which gives me the token no problem. but when I try to put it in a string I keep getting undefined.

Comment: Are you mixing between `this.$route.query.token` and `this.$route.params.token`? they're different.

Comment: Looks like this.$route.query.token.toString got me there. working now. Thanks very much Ittus, your a gent :)